# How to report a bug to sharepoint 2013 team?

Tags: report, sharepoint-2013

I have found a bug in sharepoint 2013 and i want to know whether it is already reported, if not, want to raise a bug on it. But i don't find any door opened for it, can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [microsoft sharepoint support](http://support.microsoft.com/ph/935).

Comment: It needs to buy tickets, but I just need to report a bug

Comment: link is now broken